# Updating and Upgrading - no space left on /boot

Tags: boot, upgrade

I run an Ubuntu 14.04 Server. After attempting to update and upgrade, I ran into the problems of the /boot being full. After some googling (and looking on here), I ran into [this blog post](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/) that detailed how to clean out the unused kernels. I followed all the steps, but for the final step (to actually clean out the old kernels), I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-57-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-59-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So, naturally I took the advice and tried running 'apt-get -f install'. That gave me this result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-51 linux-headers-3.16.0-51-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-51-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-utopic-tools linux-headers-3.16.0-57-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 115 not upgraded.
13 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 37.6 MB/70.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 90.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://tw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main linux-image-extra-3.16.0-57-generic amd64 3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1 [37.6 MB]
Fetched 37.6 MB in 9s (3,897 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 301552 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic_3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic (3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic_3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.16.0-59-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.16.0-59-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-59-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-59-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic_3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic (3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic_3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.16.0-57-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.16.0-57-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic_3.16.0-59.79~14.04.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-57-generic_3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I noticed that it asked me to use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove the unrequired headers and image, so I tried that as well, hoping it would free up space.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-lts-utopic-tools
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.16.0-30 linux-headers-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-44 linux-headers-3.16.0-44-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-45 linux-headers-3.16.0-45-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-46 linux-headers-3.16.0-46-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-48 linux-headers-3.16.0-48-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-52 linux-headers-3.16.0-52-generic
  linux-headers-3.16.0-57 linux-headers-3.16.0-57-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-30-generic linux-image-3.16.0-44-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-45-generic linux-image-3.16.0-46-generic
  linux-image-3.16.0-48-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-30-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-44-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-45-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-48-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-57-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.16.0-59-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 26 to remove and 115 not upgraded.
18 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/16.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 1,822 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 358771 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-headers-3.16.0-52-generic (3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.16.0-52 (3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.16.0-57-generic (3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-headers-3.16.0-57 (3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1) ...
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic (3.16.0-52.71~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-52-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.16.0-52-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.16.0-52-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_NKkAPu/lib/modules/3.16.0-52-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_NKkAPu/lib/modules/3.16.0-52-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.16.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-52-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-50-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-46-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-46-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-45-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-45-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
Removing linux-image-extra-3.16.0-57-generic (3.16.0-57.77~14.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-3.16.0-57-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.16.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-57-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-57-generic
grep: /boot/config-3.16.0-57-generic: No such file or directory
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.16.0-57-generic
Device driver support needs thus be built-in linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.16.0-57-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_8kN3GO/lib/modules/3.16.0-57-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /tmp/mkinitramfs_8kN3GO/lib/modules/3.16.0-57-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-57-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.16.0-57-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-57-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This seems to put me back at square one. My /boot/ is still full, the blog post didn't work, autoremove (with/without -f) didn't work, and I can't finish the upgrade. What do I do now?

Thanks for any help.